# Is it possible to get something similar to std::next_permutation, but doesn't always use all the letters in the string?

Tags: c++

I currently have this code

```cpp
void get_permutations(std::string s, std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        vec.push_back(s);
    } while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

and it works as intended, but next_permutation uses every character in `s`, and I would like to simply get every single combination of every character inside the string. (no duplicates)

example:

input:

```
abc
```

output:

```
a, b, c, ab, ac, abc, acb, etc
```

Is there another standard method for this or would I have to make my own?

Comment: Do you want both `ab` and `ba` to appear in the output or not? Should duplicating the characters in the input string have any effect?

Comment: yes, they should be outputted. the only limitation is that the same character should not be duplicated in the same single "output"

Comment: How about this https://godbolt.org/z/51a9qM1js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is more or less a standard approach.

Counting and bit masking will be used.

If you have some permutation of 3 letters, like "abc", then we will create bit masks like the following:

```
1.   001  -->  "--c"
2.   010  -->  "-b-"
3.   011  -->  "-bc"
4.   100  -->  "a--"
5.   101  -->  "a-c"
6.   110  -->  "ab-"
7.   111  -->  "abc"
```

You see, we simply count up, starting from 1 up to 2^(length of string). Then, for each set bit, we select one letter from the original current permutation of the string.

Since you do want only unique combinations, we use a `std::set` to eliminate duplicates.

Somehow simple . . .

One of many many possible solutions could be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

std::vector<std::string> get_permutation(std::string s)        // Yes, pass by value, make a copy
{
    std::set<std::string> result{};                            // Here we will store the result as set
    
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());                             // Sort input string in order to get permutations
    do {        
        for (size_t k = 1; k < (1 << s.length()); ++k) {       // Count and mask
            std::string combination = {};                      // Here wewill stor all possible combinations 
            for (unsigned int m{1}, i{}; m < (1 << s.length()); m <<= 1, i++) 
                if (k & m) combination += s[i];                // Add letter, if bit mask is set
            result.insert(combination);                        // Add new combination. Std::set will make it unique
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));       // And the next 3 letter permutation
    return { result.begin(), result.end() };                   // Return result as vector
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "abc";
    for (const std::string& c : get_permutation(s)) std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: is it required to pass by value?

Comment: No. Not necessarily. As always. It depends. If you want to keep the source string as is or not.